# Wrong amount of transferred Babydoge BEP20 tokens when calling transfer()

Tags: web3js, tokens, bsc, bscscan

I could create a transaction on bep20 using web3.js
The result of my transaction is here:

https://bscscan.com/tx/0xbe21da71e975cb1b092fc7838e9885704dc676b80f4decd089854f9759c1d633

The amount of asset in transaction is 252,000,000 Babydoge, but in the data section, you can see this:

```
Function: transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount)

MethodID: 0xa9059cbb
[0]:  00000000000000000000000066ab3910a28331fce99de609dd29790f76a9f4e8
[1]:  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e2c284391c0000
```

Which as you know **3e2c284391c0000** in that data is mentioning the amount I was intended to send! Which its decimal equivalent is 280,000,000 Babydoge, why?? why didn't it transfer 280,000,000 Babydoge??

Interesting point is 280,000,000 - 28,000,000 = 252,000,000 which is happened in transaction actually, Where's wrong that I couldn't see?

Any help would be hightly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because BabyDoge token has [a token transfer tax](https://twitter.com/bytes032/status/1644261171787169794) feature.

For ERC-20 tokens, `transfer()` function can have an arbitrary implementation and do whatever they want, including not giving you the right amount of tokens.

Most of tokens doing trickery like this are scams.

Comment: but what you say about [link](https://bscscan.com/tx/0xd4e37b6675ae7588907bd912aba41ee00d296ad700274b7a4e5fbaf2020b812e)
that's the same token, with a correct execution of transfer() function

Comment: I don't care what your link says. Neither does a blockchain. You can to go BSCScan and read the source code of the Babydoge contract yourself. I gave you a correct answer and any argument about is waste of time.

Comment: sorry buddy, I have no idea how the contract of babydoge is written, I have no experience in there, I just say from the same contract, there are some transactions which I showed you in that link, which act normal, why did my transaction go wrong?...

Comment: yeah, you were right, babydoge has this [policy](https://www.fool.com/the-ascent/cryptocurrency/articles/7-things-to-know-before-you-buy-baby-doge-coin/) on every transaction